# sheet names in an array but not always the same sheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a pdf of the various sheet in the workbook based on certain criteria in VBA
my current code is

```vb
Sub ExportAsPDF()

Dim FolderPath As String

FolderPath = "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\PDF\pdftest"
      'sheet names in ""
    
    Sheets(Array("SHEET1","SHEET2","SHEET3")).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=FolderPath, _
        openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
MsgBox "All PDFs have been successfully exported."

End Sub
```

the above works but there are more than 9 sheets and sometimes sheet 2 will be needed sometimes it won't. how do I write the array selection to a variable based on criteria?

if a=1 then add sheet 2 to the array kind thing

Thank You for your help!

Comment: Knowing the criteria for excluding sheet 2 would help with a solution.  For instance, if cell "A3" = some condition then include/exclude sheet 2 in the selection.  I mean if then is simple in VBA.  If condition Then do stuff closed out by typing End If.

Comment: I'm trying to get this line  Sheets(Array("SHEET1","SHEET2","SHEET3")).Select in variable form for starters then if addit=true then somehow add say sheet8 to the list but I can't get the ("sheet1", "sheet2") into a variable that works

Comment: Could you print the whole workbook and hide the sheets you don't want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an array with the sheet names, then add Sheet2 if required:

```vb
Dim arr, test

test = True 'variable which controls adding sheet2....
arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet5") 'array without sheet2

'need to add sheet2?
If test Then
    ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr)) = "Sheet2"
End If

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arr).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Tester\tempo.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: This works !! Thanks to one and all for your help! I really appreciate the array info at the bottom also Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on the described requirements.

This example assumes:

- You only want to consider excluding *Sheet2* from the pdf.
- You deterime if *Sheet2* is to be included or not by the value in Cell `B1` on `Sheet2`

I've adapted some `If...Then` conditioning with a `For Each...Next` loop to your existing code.

```
Sub ExportAsPDF()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim SheetsArray As Variant
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim ArrayCounter As Long: ArrayCounter = 0

FolderPath = "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\PDF\pdftest"
      'sheet names in ""
      
    If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = "Yes" Then
        ReDim SheetsArray(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 1)
        For Each TargetSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            SheetsArray(ArrayCounter) = TargetSheet.Name
            ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
        Next TargetSheet
    Else
        ReDim SheetsArray(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 2)
        For Each TargetSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Not TargetSheet.Name = "Sheet2" Then
                SheetsArray(ArrayCounter) = TargetSheet.Name
                ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1
            End If
        Next TargetSheet
    End If
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsArray).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath, _
        openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
MsgBox "All PDFs have been successfully exported."

End Sub
```

If the value of `Sheet2.Range("B1")` is "Yes" then Sheet2 is included in the pdf, otherwise if it's any other value it is not included.

---

### Explanation:

Relevant documentation:

- [Using Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays) (Covers setting lower/upper bound of array etc.)
- [If...Then...Else statement (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement)
- [For...Next statement (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement)

First I evaluate whether `Sheet2.Range("B1") = "Yes"` to dictate how we will populate the `SheetsArray`.

The statements are very similar depending on if it's `"Yes"` or not.

The `ReDim SheetsArray` is to set the dimension of our Array. Because arrays in VBA are `Base 0` by default *(meaning the first element of the array is 0, the second element is 1 etc...)* I size the array as follows:

- If the value is `"Yes"` the array is sized as 1 less than the number of worksheets. This is to account for the array starting at 0 rather than 1.
- If the value is not `"Yes"` then the array is sized at 2 less than the number of worksheets. This accounts for the array starting at 0 rather than 1 AND that we are not including `Sheet2`.

The `For Each...Next` loop then iterates over the `Worksheets` collection, adding each worksheet name to the array. We have an extra `If...Then` statement within the code block for if the value is not `"Yes"` to determine if the `TargetSheet` is not `Sheet2` and add the worksheet name if this condition is met. This will exclude `Sheet2` from being added to our array.

The `ArrayCounter` variable simply increments with each worksheet name added to the array as *"To set the value of an individual element, you specify the element's index."*

Answer (score 0):

```
Function AvoidWB2() As String()
Dim v() As String, i As Long, wbCount As Long

wbCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ReDim v(1 To wbCount)
For i = 1 To wbCount
    If i = 2 Then
        'do something here regarding adding sheet 2.
    Else
       v(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    End If
Next i
AvoidWB2 = v
End Function



Sub ExportAsPDF()

Dim FolderPath As String, vSheetSelection() as Variant

FolderPath = "C:\Users\USER1\Desktop\PDF\pdftest"
      'sheet names in ""
    '----| Implement Here| 
    Sheets(AvoidWB2).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=FolderPath, _
        openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
   
MsgBox "All PDFs have been successfully exported."

End Sub
```